# Is there any way to put extras to Intent from preferences?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, extras

Hi i'm launching activity from preferences screen. Activity is shared among three preferences.
I wonder if i can set extras for this activity in xml

```
<Preference
    android:key="action_1"
    android:title="@string/action_1_title"
>
    <intent
        android:action="com.package.SHAREDACTION"
    >

    </intent>
</Preference>
```

i wonder if i can do something like

```
<extras>
     <item
      android:name=""
      android:value=""/>
</extras>
```

All i need to do to pass an integer really. I can different actions and check action instead of extras.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948479/extras-on-email-intent-preferences-xml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As your extras are not constants, you should pass them in the java code instead of xml.

```
Intent intent = new Intent( this, YourTargetActivity.class );
intent.putExtra( EXTRAS_KEY, extras );
yourPref.setIntent( intent );
```

Comment: I know that,  but  i  need to pass a value when selecting a preference defined in xml.

Comment: hmm but you can retrieve a xml defined preference in the code also.

Comment: Thomas - i'm going accept your answer - have to implement OnPreferenceClickListener, get the intent from preference and then add extra. Was kind of hoping that it can be done from xml - oh well.

Answer (score 114):

I got an answer, you can use it like this:

```
<Preference
    android:key="xxx"
    android:title="xxx"
    android:summary="xxx">
   <intent android:action="xxx" >
         <extra android:name="xxx" android:value="xxx" />
    </intent>        

</Preference>
```

Comment: What do you use for `android:name`? I tried to send a mail and added `android.intent.extra.EMAIL` but it does not work.

Comment: the name is your own extra key name, then you can retrieve the value of this extra using activity.getIntent().getStringExtra(xxx) where xxx is your *name*

Comment: @EthanLeroy Late response, but the `android.intent.extra.EMAIL` extra won't work in XML because it is expecting a `String[]`, and using arrays as extras in XML isn't supported. It has to be done in code.

Comment: Android Studio (v2.2.2) Problem (just in Design Mode): **Exception raised during rendering: <extra> requires an android:value or android:resource attribute at Binary XML file line #-1**. Though I used `android:value="xxx"`. Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: If you get "Element extra is not allowed here" in Android Studio, just ignore it, everything is working fine with extra tag :)

Comment: @MichaF. there seems to be a bug report open for that https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230209

Answer (score 13):

There is a data field for intents described in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData%28%29).

It is used in the API demo application for the XML preferences to launch an intent in the Intent Preferences example.

Related example xml from that demo in preferences.xml:

```
    <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="@string/title_intent_preference"
            android:summary="@string/summary_intent_preference">

        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:data="http://www.android.com" />

    </PreferenceScreen>
```

Maybe this approach could work for you?

Answer (score 13):

Add the preference to the preference.xml file:

```
<Preference android:title="user" android:key="user"/>
```

And then you can use a setOnPreferenceClickListener to launch an Intent with extras.

```
Preference userButton = (Preference) findPreference("user");
userButton.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourTargetActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA, mUser);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

working for me.

```
<shortcut
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/xxx"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/xxx"
    android:shortcutId="xxxx"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="xxx"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="xxx">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetClass="xxx"
        android:targetPackage="xxx">
        <extra
            android:name="intent_name"
            android:value="true" />
    </intent>
</shortcut>
```

Comment: Did you receive extra value in Activity oncreate like this Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<PreferenceScreen
        android:title="@string/title_intent_preference"
        android:summary="@string/summary_intent_preference">

    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="hello world" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

to send the intent data. Then in your activity simply use:

```
getIntent().getDataString()
```

Answer (score 1):

To send email or rate on market you need to use something like

```
<Preference
        android:title="@string/title_intent_preference"
        android:summary="@string/summary_intent_preference">

    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="market://details?id=com.your_package" />

</Preference>
<Preference
        android:title="@string/title_intent_preference"
        android:summary="@string/summary_intent_preference">

    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="mailto:your_email@gmail.com" />

</Preference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but very much related. Maybe someone will find it useful.
For newer API (>11) you have a preference-headers file and you can define custom intents for one of the headers. I was trying to add a custom Extra to one of the headers and the solution I found goes like this:

In your preference-headers.xml:

```
<header 
        android:fragment="com.mypackage.MyPreference$Prefs1Fragment"
        android:title="Intent"
        android:summary="Launches an Intent.">
</header>
```

In your "MyPreference" class (extends PreferenceActivity) you have:

```
public static class Prefs1Fragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyTargetActivity.class);
        // set the desired extras, flags etc to the intent
        intent.putExtra("customExtra", "Something that I used to know");
        // starting our target activity
        startActivity(intent);
        // ending the current activity, which is just a redirector to our end goal
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```