# Open fragment from Preference fragment; Change action bar layout from nested Preference screen on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, nested, preference, preferencescreen

1. I've got `PreferenceFragment` added in activity, so I see my preferences (and the most important I see my custom action bar). But this fragment has nested preference screens inside and when I click one of those then action bar is changed to default one (nested preference screen is probably new activity?).

   How can I remain with my custom set Action bar, please?
2. In that `PreferencesFragment` I need to have an "About us" button which shows some text (So probably show other framgent).

Comment: Simlar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862299/toolbar-is-hidden-in-nested-preferencescreen

Answer (score 3):

OK I made work-around, for preference screens I made custom activity which I start from preferences and this activity has another preference fragment in it based on intent's extra

Sources for accomplishing that:
[Android: Start Activity from preferences.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275015/android-start-activity-from-preferences-xml)
[Is there any way to put extras to Intent from preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082640/is-there-any-way-to-put-extras-to-intent-from-preferences)

If anyone has better solution I'll be happy to accept is as answer, but until then I'll go with mine :)