# How can I disable focusable for all XML tags I have?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-xml

I'm writing an Android application in Android Studio on Java.

I know that there is `android:focusable="false"`, but I have too many files for doing this with every tag in XML.

How can I prevent all of them from being focused? Or maybe there is some ways that I can do it easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could think of is creating BaseActivity and BaseFragment classes and in **onCreate** and **onViewCreated** recursively go through all the views and call **setFocusable(false)**.

Here is an answer how to do it recursively:

[Loop through all subviews of an Android view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597230/loop-through-all-subviews-of-an-android-view)

Also here I handled a case with a recursion myself. I have posted an answer:

[Toolbar is hidden in nested PreferenceScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862299/toolbar-is-hidden-in-nested-preferencescreen/43003973#43003973)

Comment: wow it's really looks genius for me right now