# Not able to find "extra" attribute in jetpack preference in Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-preferences

Am trying to build Settings kind of App, I choose to use Preferences to build UI .
I am using jet pack preferences (androidx.preference.Preference) ,
If I want to launch fragment with some extras ,can use below with normal preference .

```
   <com.android.xyz.ItemsTextPreference
  android:key="xyz"
  android:title="Fragment One"
  android:visibility="invisible"
  android:fragment="com.android.xyz.MyFragment"
  <extra android:name="one" android:value="first fragment" />
</com.android.xyz.ItemsTextPreference>
```

But in Jetpack preference , there is no "extra" attribute .

Any alternative way to send extra from preference view ?

Comment: Found a similar question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082640/is-there-any-way-to-put-extras-to-intent-from-preferences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution , earlier my Preference screen having only below schema, which is from jetpack.

```
 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

After adding one more schema from traditional preference from android, like below .

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

I can use combo to achieve result .

```
<com.android.xyz.ItemsTextPreference
    android:key="xyz"
    android:title="Fragment One"
    app:isPreferenceVisible="false">
   <extra android:name="one" android:value="first fragment" />
</com.android.xyz.ItemsTextPreference>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your extra attribute inside the intent attribute
something like this:

```
<com.android.xyz.ItemsTextPreference
    android:key="xyz"
    android:title="Fragment One"
    android:visibility="invisible">
   <intent android:action="your_action" >
         <extra android:name="one" android:value="first fragment" />
    </intent>        

</com.android.xyz.ItemsTextPreference>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works with traditional preference , not with jetpack preference ,jetpack not supporting extra attribute .<com.android.xyz.ItemsTextPreference
    app:key="xyz"
    app:title="Fragment One"
    app:isPreferenceVisible="false">
   <intent app:action="your_action" >
         <extra app:name="one" app:value="first fragment" />
    </intent>        

</com.android.xyz.ItemsTextPreference> This code gave compilation error .